# Embedding Power BI dashboards and reports

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

[image: PowerBI embed diagram]

Have I understood the auth process correctly for embedding Power BI content where users need not auth themselves against Power BI? Is [adal](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python) Python library the library I want to use to auth against Azure AD?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
Any Valid Azure Active Directory (AAD) token can be used, regardless of how it's retrieved.

You can use Python, AJAX, ADAL.js, C# .NET or whatever you'd like

Comment: Thanks. Currently we acquire an AAD token via plain-text username:password credentials (stored on the server) for the PowerBI master user. What other methods are there to (securely) store PowerBI credentials for a master user on the server?

Comment: You can always use secure storage servers, like [Azure Key-Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) or some other secure servers

Comment: Thanks again. What is your opinion on authenticating using a master account username & password (regardless of whether the credentials are stored securely)? Are you aware of any other methods more suited for production environments, such as certificates/keyfiles/etc.?

Comment: In a few months, there will be another authentication method introduced to Power BI Embedded, called AppOnlyToken, which will no longer be based on a single\few master users but the application identity itself, but this is not public yet. Look for product announcements more towards the summer.

A master user, as in 'AppOwnsData' is the recommended way to go as the official way from the Microsoft Power BI Embedded product team